# Can historical EmailMessageRelation records be migrated? (CreatedDate is not writeable even with relevant permissions)

Tags: soql, emailmessage, data-migration

I am unclear how one can migrate EmailMessageRelation records because the 'CreatedDate' field is not writeable even with the relevant permissions ('Edit access on Read Only fields' and 'System Audit Fields').

Below is a screenshot from Workbench which shows that 'CreatedDate' doesn't even appear as a row in the Data | Insert operation.

I haven't found any documentation yet on this particular nuance; which is odd as I was expecting that this object could and should be migrated over.

1. Is it possible to migrate historical EmailMessageRelation records to
   a new Salesforce org?
2. And if not, is there any reasoning behind why they should not be
   migrated over?

[image]

Comment: I seem to recall a few times where people mentioned enabling editing of system and/or audit fields (might need to call support to get that enabled). Not something I'm familiar with, and certain;y not enough to make an answer, but it is a possible avenue to explore.

Comment: Hi Derek - I already have these permissions enabled. Hence, why I'm extra confused why CreatedDate for this particular object is not writeable.